# Hear Sound File in File Browser?

Tags: audio, file-browser

I'm making a video with Blender's video editing feature, and I was wondering if blender lets you listen to a sound file while its in the file browser, before you insert it into the sequencer.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a shot